# How to get value from additional column in the quote_item table to show it on the checkout page?

Tags: magento2

So what I have done so far is adding new value to the `quote_item` table using an observer. the column name is `expected_delivery_time`.

Now the column `expected_delivery_time` will be populated for the product which added to the cart.

I see the column `expected_delivery_time` is exist and has the value whenever I see the page source.

Now I would like to show this column value in the checkout page to the users on each selected product.

How do I achieve this ?

For some reason simple thing is not easy in magento 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are js file in magento 2 called `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'` You can use this to get the `expected_deliver_time` value from your table.

So you can use `underscore` to looping through the `quote` and getting the `quote_item`. and the get the value like this :

```
var itemQuoteData = quote.getItems();
var result = null;
_.each(itemQuoteData, function (item) {
    if (item_id == item.item_id) {
        result = item.expected_delivery_time; // here it is.
    }
});
```

and here is the complete code use it in your js file :

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'uiLayout',
        'moment',
        'mageUtils'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        _,
        Component,
        quote,
        layout,
        moment,
        utils
    ) {
        'use strict';


            /**
             * Get Delivery Time
             * from itemQuoteData
             *
             * @param {string} item_id
             * @returns {string} dateTime
             */
            getDeliveryTime: function (item_id) {
                var itemQuoteData = quote.getItems();
                var result = null;
                _.each(itemQuoteData, function (item) {
                    if (item_id == item.item_id) {
                        result = item.expected_delivery_time; // here it is.
                    }
                });

                var deliveryTime = new Date(result.split(" ")[0]);      
                return moment(deliveryTime).format("DD MMMM YYYY");                
            },            


    }
);
```

Finding this needs research and trial and error. But it is not that hard until you know it.